# Formula used to calculate boost::hash

Tags: boost, hash

I would like to know the formula used to calculate the hash values for `Boost.Bimap`. For example if I want to know and calculate manually for integer `123456`, or bit-set `1101001` or character string `abcda`.

Comment: Really, no answer?

Comment: Really, 6 upvotes?

Answer (score 2):

Boost uses [Boost::hash](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/doc/html/boost/hash.html) for unordered containers, including Bimap. Boost::hash implementations could be found [here on Ginhub](https://github.com/boostorg/container_hash/blob/develop/include/boost/container_hash/hash.hpp).

See [hash_range](https://github.com/boostorg/container_hash/blob/f054fe932f4d5173bfd6dad5bcff5738a7aff0be/include/boost/container_hash/hash.hpp#L424) for strings, [hash_value_signed/unsigned](https://github.com/boostorg/container_hash/blob/f054fe932f4d5173bfd6dad5bcff5738a7aff0be/include/boost/container_hash/hash.hpp#L270) for integers.

You could use this snippet to calculate hash values (use your data type instead of `int`):

```
boost::hash<int> hasher;
size_t hash_value = hasher(your_int_key);
```

You could also create [custom hash function](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/doc/html/hash/custom.html) for your data types.

Comment: Thanks for providing the answer. I know how to use `boost` to calculate hash value but I want to do some manual calculation. If you can give a simple example for `integer`, that would be nice.

Comment: For simple integer types `hash` function returns the number itself. Otherwise if key type size is greater than `size_t`, this code is used: https://github.com/boostorg/container_hash/blob/f054fe932f4d5173bfd6dad5bcff5738a7aff0be/include/boost/container_hash/hash.hpp#L270